# Django using pk like int in the view function

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to make an asynchronous multiplayer game.
My idea is to share a template ('play_game.html') between players. 
So when the player 1 has the turn, then a bottom appears and when He press It, the function play_game gets a request and a one, with this one, It adds a one to the turn so, It's renders the play_game.hmtl with the next turn to play. The problem:
The game function always gets one. If I press F5 in the browser but I don't press the bottom then the value still been one. I don't know.

This is the code:

this is the function

```
@login_required
def play_game(request, flag):
    current_user = User.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
    game = current_user.game
    if int(flag) == 1:
        if game.turn < game.players_total:
            game.turn = game.turn + 1
        else:
            game.turn = 1
        game.save()
    turn = game.turn
    context = {
        'current_user' : current_user,
        'turn' : turn
    }
return render(request,'play_game.html', context)
```

This is the template play_game.html

```
 {% extends 'base.html' %}
 {% load staticfiles %}

 {% block content %}
 {% if current_user.turn == turn %}
 <p> your turn <p/>
 <li><a href="{% url 'play_game' flag=1 %}"> Move </a></li>
 {% endif %}
 {% endblock %}
```

and this is the url:

```
 url(r'^game_list/join_to_game/play_game/(?P<flag>[0-9]+)/$', views.play_game, name='play_game'),
```

The problem in other word is that the flag is always one.
What can I do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Problem in this line, you always set flag to 1:

```
<a href="{% url 'play_game' flag=1 %}">
```

Try to pass flag to the template as context variable:

```
context = {
    'current_user' : current_user,
    'turn' : turn,
    'flag' : flag 
}
```

And then inside template increase its value each time when button clicked using add filter:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'play_game' flag=flag|add:'1' %}"> Move </a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks, but It doesn't work : /. I will try with simple Post method